# Dynamically scale object stacked over another one

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a project with `three.js` where the user can dynamically change the dimensions of the model. The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880150/stack-a-cube-over-another-dynamically) that I posted, but I am afraid it is not working since this time I am working with an extrusion of a planar shape. The snippet of the code where I am having problems is the following:

```
cubeY.onChange(function(value){
     cube.scale.y = value;
     cube.position.y = (cubeHeight * value) / 2;
     roof.position.y = (roofHeight * roof.scale.y) / 2 + cube.position.y * 2 - roofHeight;});;
roofY.onChange(function(value){
    roof.scale.y = value;
    roof.position.y = ((roofHeight * value) + cube.position.y * 2) - value * roofHeight;
});
```

As you can observe, when I change `roof.scale.y`, also the object is moving but it should stay fixed to the upper part of the cube. 
Do you know what am I doing wrong? This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLxp81b/) with the complete code.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: This is the third question on the same subject but each one a little bit harder than the previous one. But all with the same common denominator. Problems with scale and object alignment based on that scale. Maybe you are thinking about this problem all wrong. I think it would be easier if your GUI actually manipulated the actual dimensions of your elements, not their scale. If you know the exact dimensions of your object elements it is much easier to align other elements on them or around them. Just a thought.

Comment: @gaitat I know, but all the examples I could find were manipulating the scale of an object, not its dimensions. But please, if you do know some examples show them to me. Thank you!!

Comment: Updated for y scaling : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLxp81b/3/)

Comment: @uhura No problem! I was just looking for the `y scale`. Post it as an answer with a little explanation, so that you can get the bounty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaled cube's height is `cubeHeight * cube.scale.y` and roof's is `roofHeight * roof.scale.y`.

Top center position of the cube (cube's height) is `cube.position.y  + cubeHeight/2 * cube.scale.y` or just `cubeHeight * cube.scale.y`

Roof's geometric center is not coordinate system center so it's position is cube's height minus half roof's height

```
cube.position.y  + cubeHeight/2 * cube.scale.y  - roofHeight/2 * roof.scale.y
```

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLxp81b/3/)